# Is there a way to detect the color theme of the user's OS with Javascript or CSS? (not light/dark mode)

Tags: javascript, css

What I'm looking for is the colors of the users theme not light/dark mode.

For example if the user has a *blue* theme selected in their OS I'd like to get the color code of that blue color. Same if the user has a *red*, *pink*, *yellow* or whatever theme selected.

I know you kan check if the OS is light/dark mode but that doesn't really tell me anything about the users preferred colors.

If there isn't a way to do this, are there any plans for such features?

Comment: Something like [this proposal](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/5826)?

Comment: Seems to be more like the color of the device rather than OS theme color. But the page links to some other interesting things like [#575](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/575) and [#1693](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1693).